# Toggling the 'muted' attribute of HTML5 audio

Tags: jquery, html, audio, toggle, mute

I am trying to create a mute/unmute button, I'm quite new to jquery so it would be helpful if anyone could give me any pointers:

```
$("#dinner").click(function() {
       var bool = $("#player").muted;
       $("#player").attr("muted",!bool);
});
```

Comment: #player is an ordinary html5 <audio> player

Comment: `var bool = $("#player").muted` should be `var bool = $("#player")[0].muted`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fixed it, the 'muted' attribute is actually a property:

```
$("#dinner").click(function() {
        var bool = $("#player").prop("muted");
        $("#player").prop("muted",!bool);
});
```

This can also be done slightly more succinctly by using ES6 arrow functions and also by providing a function to `prop()` which accepts the current state of the property as an argument. In this case the code would look something like this:

```
$('#dinner').on('click', () => $('#player').prop('muted', (_, muted) => !muted));
```