# How do you mute a html object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to mute an object tag? This for example doesn't work.

```
<object data="games/shadez2" muted="true"></object>
```

id like to know in html or jquery please so that i can do a click function to mute it.

```
$(window).click(function(){
if ( event.target.tagName !== "object" ) {
// mute
} else {
// unmute
}
});
```

Comment: same way how you can mute a video, lets say im using an object tag so that users can play a game, what if they stop playing the game. i want the audio to be muted if they click off of the game. Similar to what you find on Kongregate.com and other online game websites.

Comment: There is no concept of 'mute' in reference to an object or embed HTML element. You would need to look into using the embedded game's API to mute the game audio.

Comment: by the way if anyone wants to test if their answer will work you can download a game from crazymonkegames.com http://www.crazymonkeygames.com/download.php and then create a quick html document with an object tag.

Comment: To start with `<Object>`s are not HTML5. You will have to look into talking to the Flash ActionScript from JavaScript. Otherwise I'd recommend to implement the mute function in the flash file itself instead. Furthermore, Flash (SWF) is "dead" - avoid using it whenever possible

Comment: What would you recommend for games on a website if flash should be avoided?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try muted as a property?

```
<object data="games/shadez3" muted></object>
```

or check this post, maybe can help you

[Toggling the 'muted' attribute of HTML5 audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409992/toggling-the-muted-attribute-of-html5-audio)

Comment: yes i tried it as shows in the question. That doesnt work on object tags, it only works on video and audio tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try a boolean to toggle.
var bool = $(*target*).prop("muted");